# semigroup of operator under the norm $L(U,E)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, semigroup-of-operators, stochastic-pde

Let $E, U$ be two Banach spaces.
Let $(S(t),t\in[0,T]) : U\to E$ be a semigroup of bounded linear operator.
What does
\begin{align*}
 |S(t)|_{L(U,E)}
\end{align*}
   mean explicitly?
 I think, the above is by  definition (of operator norm), namely
 \begin{align*}
  |S_t|_{L(U,E)} :=\sup_{|x|_U\le 1}|S_t(x)|_E\le C|x|_U\quad C\,\,\text{depends on $S_t$}
 \end{align*}
 Could anyone correct me above? How can one see $C$ depends on $S(t)$, can someone show me?

Comment: You are right; this is the definition of the operator norm. What do you mean by "more explicit"?

Comment: i meant, if I take $U$ some sobolev space, then i can obtain a explicit bound on the rhs.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about $U$ being a Sobolev space. Of course in that case you can use any Sobolev norm inequalities that apply in the situation you have.

Comment: Can you answer my question that how can I see $C$ depends on $S_t$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Of course it depends on $S_t$. What is the question?